# In-Game Calendar

Tags: tools, shadowrun

I play Shadowrun with my group. We have a blog and I as GM wish that we could somehow track our in-game calendar.

How many days have gone by? When does lifestyle have to be paid? How many days 'til the run?

Do you have an ideas for how to set up an online, in-game calendar? Better would be if there is a widget where you can see the next events.

[EDIT] Ok let's go a little bit deeper. I wish i could have something like a widget where the next in-game events are shown with date. The prolem with all onlne caldar-tools I found is that the use the actual day for next vents.

Comment: Use a real tool, just set the dates in the far future?...

Comment: Since this is for Shadowrun, which shares our calendar, there are lots of real-world calendaring tools that you could use. This would be a much different question if you wanted a tool or setup that would handle any arbitrary made-up calendar.

Comment: Ah, given your edit, nothing I know of exists. You could hack an existing blog widget, but then it's a programming question.

Comment: Not a shopping question. One could probably answer it with a tool recommendation, but that's not the question is asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be overthinking things a bit.  It's entirely possible for you to say in your blog post "The next game will take place on [Real Date] and [Time1] will have gone by in game since the end of the last session. Please/I will subtract lifestyle costs (so please tell me which you want for this month).  You have [Time2] until the next run."

Although for a more direct and usable method, you could always sign onto Google Docs and make a spreadsheet for the calendar, and gray out all in game days that have passed.  It's relatively easy to make a template sheet and c/p it with different month names, and all you have to do is set the sharing permissions (which can be as broad as "public" for something this free-form as not to force them to have a google account).

Answer (score 0):

It is not an online tool, but maybe the principle can be expanded. I always just used a paper calendar with pins for each character. That way when it came time to play, we knew who was available when and who had time to account for before they could join the next foray.

As such any calendar tool could likely be used if you were willing to overlook it paying mind to the real date. If Google calendar grays out all the dates in the past, but they are still valid game appointments, so be it.